# Display a UIAlertView with a countdown?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, count, uialertview

I want to display a countdown of 3 seconds within a UIAlertView. Once the countdown is up, the user will be redirected to the next level of a game, and the alert will be dismissed. But how can I display the current countdown int in the UIAlertView?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to create your own custom UIView.

Answer (score 2):

When you create the `UIAlertView` try holding onto the pointer and using an `NSTimer` to update the `message` or `title` property every second.